# EXCEL - Sum fixed range based in complex multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 tables:

1. SALES
   Sale ID
   Provider Sell Count ID
   Client
   Provider
   Commission
2. COMMISSION PAYMENTS
   Sales Range
   Provider
   Amount Payed
3. COMMISSION AGENTS
   Client
   Agent Name
   Commission %

I need to calculate the amount that corresponds to each Commission Agent only from commissions that were already paid.

To do so i should use Sales Range in Commission Payments table and get all sales that are within that range and are from same provider in Sales table.

The Sales Range comes from the Provider Sell Count ID field in Sales Table. 
That way i can have a record of which sales commissions have been payed for each provider.

Then i have to check for each of them who's the client, check whose agent is that client from (based on the data on the third table) and multiply the commission amount by the commission percentage that corresponds to him.

I guess i should use some complex combination of MATCHs and INDEXs but couldnt get it to work, any ideas?

I hope i made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by loading each table into the Data Model (on the Power Pivot ribbon), then create relationships between the tables, measures for the calculations, and finally a pivot table to display the results.

If you don't have Power Pivot, you will need to bring the data into one table. Create helper columns and populate them with lookup functions, then perform the calculation on that consolidated table.

Comment: Forgot to mention im using excel for mac, i think thats not possible, is it?

Comment: No, Mac doesn't have Power Pivot. I added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Thanks i've seen it, it gives me an idea of what should i do, im just wondering something, in Commission Payments Table in Sales Range i input a text like this 1-5 containing the range of ID's, how can i make the new table that will auto plot with all the bookings (1,2,3,4 and 5) between the range? Im guessing ill have to use index >= and <= but how do i make it automatic for it to happen with every row that contains a range (it could also have only 1 number but when thats the case i get the info i need in very same table)

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, since I cannot see your data. If you need flexible tables, consider Pivot Tables instead of formulas.